# The property author is not recognized by Google for an object of type Thing

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am new to Google rich snippets and I did some basic research on Google rich snippets and added following code to my site:

```html
<div class='reiew-rating'>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">

<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
<meta itemprop="name" content=" Interview questions" />
<meta itemprop="description" content=" for entry level/juniors/freshers &amp; experienced/seniors" /><meta itemprop="url" content="" />
  <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="name" Content="Suresh babu mamidala">
  </span>
<img id="6_1" src="http://callinterview.com/images/rating_full.png"  alt="rating_1" data-rat="1" >
<img id="6_2" src="http://callinterview.com/images/rating_full.png"   alt="rating_2" data-rat="2" >
<img id="6_3" src="http://callinterview.com/images/rating_full.png"   alt="rating_3" data-rat="3" >
<img id="6_4" src="http://callinterview.com/images/rating_full.png"   alt="rating_4" data-rat="4" >
<img id="6_5" src="http://callinterview.com/images/rating_avg.png"   alt="rating_5" data-rat="5" >

</div>
 
  <div property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating">
   <span property="ratingValue">4.5</span>

 <meta property="bestRating" content="5"/>
      <meta property="worstRating" content="1"/>
       based on <span property="ratingCount">7869</span> ratings
        </div>
     <span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Callinterview.com">

     
</div>
</div>
```

When I test it in the [Google structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), I am facing following error/s:

> The property author is not recognized by Google for an object of type Thing.
>
> A value for the author field is required.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the `author` property to the `Thing`:

```html
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <!-- … -->
    <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <!-- … -->
    </span>
</div>
```

But the [`author` property](http://schema.org/author) is not defined for the [`Thing` type](http://schema.org/Thing).

If it’s the `author` of the `Review`, you have to make sure not to nest it under a different `itemscope`, e.g.:

```html
<div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <!-- … -->
</div>

<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <!-- … -->
</span>
```